# Pass php variable to JQuery ajax in a different file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to pass variables from php to Jquery to comfirm that the `INSERT` query is a success. 
first the `$msg` variable has an empty string by default and then once `mysqli_num_rows` if statement is true the `$msg` variable will not be empty anymore 
Here is my php

```
$errfname = $errlname = $errusername= $errpassword = $msg= "";

$status=1;
$message="Success";

    if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
        $errfname = "Please enter First Name";

        $emptyfname['emptyfname'] = $errfname;
        echo json_encode($emptyfname);

    }else{
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $emptyfname['emptyfname'] = "";
        echo json_encode($emptyfname);

    }

    if (empty($_POST['lname'])) {
        $errlname = "Please enter Last Name";

    }else{
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $errusername = "Please enter First Name";
    }else{
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $errpassword = "Please enter Password";
    }else{
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }

    if ($errfname=="" && $errlname=="" && $errusername=="" && $errpassword=="") {
        $exist = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $exist);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
              $status=0;
            $message="Usermame exist";
                        $array=array('status' => $status,
            'message' => $message);
        echo json_encode($array); 
        }

        else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (fname,lname,username,password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$username','$password')";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        }

    }



?>
```

In the js file i want to pass the php variable which is `$msg` so I can do something with it. What I want to do is if the variable `$msg` is empty which means its a success then I will redirect user to the main page

Here is the js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
             var me = $(this);
             e.preventDefault();
             if ( me.data('requestRunning') ) {
                return;
            }

            me.data('requestRunning', true);
            var sendfname = $("#fname").val();
            var sendlname = $("#lname").val();
            var sendusername = $("#username").val();
            var sendpass = $("#pass").val();

                     if(sendfname == ""){
                        $("#fname").addClass("empty");
                        $("#fname").attr("placeholder", 'Please Enter First Name').focus().blur();
                    }
                     if(sendlname == ""){

                        $("#lname").addClass("empty");
                        $("#lname").attr("placeholder", 'Please Enter Last Name').focus().blur();
                    }
                    if(sendusername == ""){

                        $("#username").addClass("empty");
                        $("#username").attr("placeholder", 'Please Enter Username').focus().blur();
                    }
                    if(sendpass == ""){
                        $("#pass").addClass("empty");

                        $("#pass").attr("placeholder", 'Please Enter Password').focus().blur();
                    }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'process.php',
                 dataType: 'json',
                data: "fname=" + sendfname + "&lname="+sendlname + "&username="+sendusername + "&password="+sendpass,
                success: function(data1){
                    if(data1.status==1){
                        alert(data1.message);//success
                    }else{
                        alert(data1.message);//error
                    }


                },
                 complete: function() {
                    me.data('requestRunning', false);
                }
            }); 

         return false;

        });
```

Comment: Would it not make MORE SENCE to do you javascript validation BEFORE passing the data via AJAX call to the PHP script? I am not suggesting you dont do it in PHP as well but come on

Comment: Passing data to the ajax call `data: {fname: sendfname, lname: sendlname, username: sendusername, password: sendpass},`

Comment: i don't clearly understand it, sorry im a beginner in jquery

Comment: Thats not a jquery issue its a logical approach issue. Validate data before you do something with it, not afterwards

Comment: didnt i passed a data which is  data: "fname=" + sendfname + "&lname="+sendlname + "&username="+sendusername + "&password="+sendpass

Comment: Yea that works but its easier to read/understand/debug/pass to another devloper if you do it correctly

Comment: oooh you mean i should validate it to php?

Comment: You are validating it in PHP! But in the javascript you only validate the data taken from the page AFTER you have sent it to the PHP script via an AJAX call

Comment: can you give me an example , sorry

Comment: Did you write any of this or is it all cobbled together from bits of code you found on the internet?

Comment: this is from a video tutorial

Comment: Well I would suggest you find another tutorial where the author has ___got a clue___

Comment: do you know how to pass php variable to js?

Comment: `echo json_encode($anArrayOrAnObject);`

Comment: i already did that, looked into the same issues but didnt work for me.
like echo jason_encode($row); then in js data.row
Can you please give me example or take a piece of my code and edit it?

Comment: The result of the above echo will appear in the `data1` parameter of `.success` function

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has some serious problems 
First In your PHP file you need to define two variables.One for status and other for message

```
 $errfname = $errlname = $errusername= $errpassword = $msg= "";

 $status=1;
 $message="Success";

if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {
    $message = "Please enter First Name";
    $status=0;
}else{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
}

if (empty($_POST['lname'])) {
    $message = "Please enter Last Name";
    $status=0;
}else{
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
}

if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $message = "Please enter First Name";
    $status=0;
}else{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}

if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $message = "Please enter Password";
    $status=0;
}else{
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

if ($errfname=="" && $errlname=="" && $errusername=="" && $errpassword=="") {
    $exist = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $exist);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {          
        $message="Usermame exist";
        $status=0;                      
    }

    else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (fname,lname,username,password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$username','$password')";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if(!$result){
            $message="error";
            $status=0;
         }          
    }

}

  $array=array('status' => $status,
        'message' => $message);
    echo json_encode($array);  // send data as json format
```

your jquery code terribly wrong you are validating your data after the success of ajax response.Validate it before that.In you Jquery

```
  if(sendfname == "")
      {
         return;
      }
   //write all your validations then  write ajax
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
             dataType: 'json',
            data: "fname=" + sendfname + "&lname="+sendlname + "&username="+sendusername + "&password="+sendpass,
            success: function(data1){
                 if(data1.status==1){
                    alert(data1.message);//success
                }else{
                    alert(data1.message);//error
                }
             }
```

Comment: Parameter is `data1` not `data`

Comment: I update my code please see if its correct btw it's still not working, there is no alert if the user exist

Comment: its working now, i have one more json_encode in php and i deleted it and now its working. but how can i have multiple json_encode without having an issue